# SQL Server CTE result with except based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CTE like this:

```
with cte as
(
   -- beep boop beep
) 
select * 
from cte 
where rowNum = 1
```

returning e.g. 6 columns:

```
 a | b | c |   d   | e  | f
---+---+---+-------+----+---
 1 | i | 0 |  qwe  | :/ | r 
 1 | j | 2 |  asd  | :) | r 
 1 | k | 4 |  zxc  | :( | r
 2 | i | 0 |  qwe  | :D | r
```

I have another table that could be used as a composite key for some of these results:

```
 a | c |  d
---+---+-----
 1 | 2 | asd
 2 | 0 | qwe
```

Is there a way I can exclude rows 2 and 4 from the result set using that 2nd table **without** altering the CTE inside the brackets?

I figured joining the CTE on the exclusion table at first but the syntax said `no` - then I was trying to use the `where` clause to exclude results but actually I have no idea how to exclude on more than one column.

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing.  You have `select *`, but it doesn't include `rownum`.  Presumably, that is just an oversight.

Comment: rownum is an alias defined in the select part of cte, I want to select all columns produced  but only where the rownum is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `not exists`:

```
select cte.*
from cte
where rownum = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where e.a = cte.a and e.c = cte.c and e.d = cte.d
                 );
```

I *strongly* recommend `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery over `NOT IN`.  `NOT IN` does not behave as expected if *any* of the returned values are `NULL`.  My best advice is just to avoid using it, getting used to `NOT EXISTS`, so you don't have an unexpected problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use not in condition,

```
with cte as
(

) 
select * from cte where (a,c,d) not in 
(select a,c,d from table2);
```

Comment: TSQL unfortunately does not support tuple comparison, and you have to use EXISTS.

Comment: I love the syntax for this but it won't work with a CTE